# Why vscode extension "Lex Flex Bison Yacc" doesn't highlight the code in the .y file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bison

My vscode version is 1.39.2 for Windows. In my .y file, the code was not highlight correctly. The code between two "%%" was not highlight.

[image: highlight1]

[image: highlight2]

Comment: Not sure StackOverflow is the right place for this, this seems like a bug report that belongs on the extension's issue tracker.